Is Caesar's Bellum Gallicum the same as Commentarii de Bello Gallico?
Is Caesar's Bellum Gallicum the same as Commentarii de Bello Gallico?
Struggling to verify if these are identical texts or different. Thank you so much for any help.

Yes, they are the same work. Most resources typically mention both titles:

Caesar's only surviving works are his two histories, the Commentarii de Bello Gallico (often shortened to Bellum Gallicum) and the Commentarii de Bello Civili (often shortened to Bellum Civile).
The De Bello Gallico likely originated in reports (called commentarii) to the Senate detailing Caesar’s actions in Gaul.

This variation is actually pretty common. We don't always know an exact title, if one even existed, for ancient works, either Greek or Latin, poetry or prose.
In this case, the latter name comprises the type of work (it's a commentarius, "commentary, memoir") followed by the subject matter (de Bello Gallico = "on/about/concerning the Gallic War").
Some people find that too wordy, so they drop everything but the subject matter, leaving on Bellum Gallicum in the nominative.
You also sometimes see it without Commentarii, so just De Bello Gallico. The same thing is true for Caesar's other work: Commentarii de Bello Civili, Bellum Civile, or De Bello Civili.
Other works can vary by a greater degree. For example, Lucan's epic poem on Civil War is either called Bellum Civile or Pharsalia.

I nominate as the record holder for widely diverging titles: Cornelius Nepos with his De viris illustribus, or was it Vitae excellentium imperatorum, no wait, De excellentibus ducibus exterarum gentium, or maybe …
